# Sincronizar repositorios en tiempo real

Tags: laravel, ftp

Estoy empezando un nuevo proyecto con laravel en un hosting compartido.

Mi pregunta es si conocen alguna forma de sincronizar el proyecto que está en local con el proyecto que esta en el hosting. Estoy utilizando visual studio code como editor de código.

Actualmente tengo configurado ftp simple y funciona bien si los cambios fueran directamente en el hosting.

La cuestión es que estoy utilizando nodejs para para compilar mi frontend y al momento de generar nuevos archivos css, js, fonts, imgs, etc. Los archivos se reflejan en mi proyecto local pero no se reproducen automáticamente en el hosting.

¿Alguien conoce de algún plugin o programa que me ayude a emparejar en tiempo real los archivos entre los dos proyectos?

Comment: Creo que esta pregunta está al límite en cuanto a estar basada en opiniones o no. Hay varias preguntas: ¿acaso no hay un control de versiones? por aquello de sincronizar en tiempo real, no estoy muy seguro que sea una buena idea eso de «sincronizar». Por otra parte, el problema de los hosting compartidos es que limitan gran cantidad de las opciones de sincronización o de deploys automáticos. Tal vez ftp sea la mejor opción para medio sincronizar los archivos, pero pensar en poder compilar assets de frontend, creo que habría que evaluar primero las capacidades del servidor compartido.

Comment: Si estoy versionando con git en local. De echo solo requiero que cuando se genere, modifique o elimine  un nuevo archivo en local automáticamente el ftp haga lo mismo en el hosting.

Comment: Vi que se puede hacer con filezilla pero no me esta emparejando las carpetas automáticamente.

Comment: Aún así me parece una solución demasiado riesgosa sincronizar automáticamente con producción.

Comment: Bueno si tienes razón pero no se me ocurre otra forma de poder trabajarlo este proyecto.

Comment: Es solo mi opinión pero se debería tener el control de cuando quiero hacer un deploy o no. Independiente que sea ftp, ssh o cualquier otro método, una sincronización automática es riesgosa, o se debería tener una forma de regresar a una versión anterior rápidamente. Todo esto lo digo por experiencia y por conocimiento de muchos proyectos (muy grandes) donde han tenido inconvenientes por querer aplicar cosas así.

Comment: Pero si hay algún problema puedo utilizar un comit estable de git en local lo cual, aria que los repositorios en el hosting se actualizaran a una versión estable del proyecto.  Eso si ya lo había contemplado. Por eso no veía el inconveniente. Lo veo más por el lado del la seguridad. Si en algún momento lanzo un cambio que vulnere el desarrollo, hasta que me de cuenta seria cuando lo corregiría.

Comment: Hay muchas cosas realmente inesperadas que podrían ocurrir con automatizaciones de este tipo, la vulnerabilidad es solo una de ellas.